# Switching from one menu to another in Angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 menu `Administration` and `Market` with sub menus.

[image]

The `Administration` menu works correctly

If I click on `Account Opening` it works ! The page appears with the link

**http://localhost:4200/administration/account-opening**

[image]

If I click on `Portfolio` it works also ! The page appears with the link

**http://localhost:4200/administration/portfolio**

[image]

My problem is that if I click on `Market` for example on `Value` from the administration url, I don't switch to the url **http://localhost:4200/market/indice**.

Here is a screenshot...I'm still on the url:

**http://localhost:4200/administration/portfolio**

[image]

However, If if change the url manually

http://localhost:4200/administration/portfolio

[image]

By

http://localhost:4200/market/indice

The `Indice` page works !

[image]

How I can communicate from the "Administration" and "Market" section in 1 click????

I don't want the user enters the url manually to navigate the site, it will be tedious.

I think the problem is on the dashboard.component.ts ? Perhaps that the routes are incorrect

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedTab: string | undefined;

  showSubmenu: any[] = [];
  showInfo: any[] = [];

  menus: any[] = [
    /* Administration */
    {
      class: 'bx bx-lock-alt',
      item: 'Administration',
      route: 'administration',
      arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
      arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',

      submenus: [
        {
          class: 'bx bx-key',
          item: 'Account Opening',
          route: 'account-opening',
        },
        {
          class: 'bx bx-wallet',
          item: 'Portfolio',
          route: 'portfolio',
        },
      ],
    },

    /* Market */
    {
      class: 'bx bx-chart',
      item: 'Market',
      route: 'market',
      arrowDown: 'bx bx-chevron-down',
      arrowUp: 'bx bx-chevron-up',

      submenus: [
        {
          class: 'bx bx-coin-stack',
          item: 'Value',
          route: 'value',
        },
        {
          class: 'bx bx-line-chart',
          item: 'Indice',
          route: 'indice',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleMenu(index: number) {
    this.showSubmenu[index] = !this.showSubmenu[index];
  }

  toggleSubmenu(event: MouseEvent, item: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.showInfo[item] = !this.showInfo[item];
  }
}
```

Here is an idea of the structure

[image]

I can share the project with you at this link, if you want?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hkryrg?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have defined all the routes as relatives.

So when you are in **/localhost:4200/administration/account-opening** and click on market it tries to navigate to **/localhost:4200/administration/market**. You can see it in the error thrown in the console.

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'administration/market'
```

To solve it in this specific case, you could add a forward-slash `/` in the administration and market routes, to make them absolute.

```
menus: any[] = [
    /* Administration */
    {
      ...
      route: '/administration',
      ...
    },

    /* Market */
    {
      ...
      route: '/market',
      ...
    },
  ];
```

cheers